# What is the difference between 'Doc root var' and 'Owner var' in CocosBuilder

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocosbuilder

In CocosBuilder, there is a **Code Connections** section. At second line, it has three options: **Don't Assign**, **Doc root var** and **Owner var**.

Sometimes, I got a error when I was selecting **Owner var**, but it works fine after I changed it to **Doc root var**.

I google a lot, but can't find a satisfied answer.

Does anyone can explain the difference clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't assign** simply means that you are not using the **Code Connections**.

**Doc root var** means that you are connecting a custom cocos2d class. This will glue/connect the object in your document (CCB stage/file) to your code. This option is convenient but you must make sure that root node's controller object is provided.

> Sometimes you need to be able to access member variables from and get
>   callbacks to another object than the root node of a ccb-file. To do
>   this you will need to pass an owner to the CCBReader.

as explained in [Connecting with cocos2d-x](https://github.com/cocos2d/CocosBuilder/blob/develop/Documentation/4c.%20Connecting%20with%20cocos2d-x.md).

**Owner var** provides you with [more flexibility](https://github.com/cocos2d/CocosBuilder/blob/develop/Documentation/4c.%20Connecting%20with%20cocos2d-x.md#passing-an-owner-variable) by allowing you to connect to a variable other than the root node. You can glue it to any variable of your choosing.

The error you are getting is most likely caused by providing a name that is not available (the variable doesn't exist). Note that setting the property to **Doc root var** or **Owner var** and leaving the field empty will cause this error.

Comment: I can make sure after I changed property, I kept the value unchanged. But thank you all the same.

Answer (score 2):

When [linking member variables](https://github.com/cocos2d/CocosBuilder/blob/master/Documentation/4a.%20Connecting%20with%20Cocos2d%20JS.md#linking-member-variables) the **Doc root var** will add a member in the root node's controller object. You could access it via `MainScene.myVar` assuming that you JS Controller is MainScene. This is defined by your scene root layer JS Controller property.

Alternatively, you can do the same thing with a custom object that is not directly tied to the scene via the JS Controller connection. To achieve this, you would use the **Owner var** attribute.

**Don't Assign** is the default and doesn't do anything.

In essence, these features allows you to easily reference those CCB objects from your code.

Experimenting with the [CocosBuilder JS Example Games](http://cocosbuilder.com/?page_id=11) may be of help. The documentation on [how to connect with cocos2d-x](https://github.com/cocos2d/CocosBuilder/blob/develop/Documentation/4c.%20Connecting%20with%20cocos2d-x.md) might also be useful to you if you didn't read it yet.

Comment: Thank you for your post, but I didn't want **Connecting with Cocos2d JS**, and in how to connect with cocos2d-x, it doesn't describe the difference.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I've only noticed the cocos2d-x flag after writing my answer. Since it is now the only answer I figured it might still inspire you. I'll refrain from commenting about cocos2d-x since I did not use it in conjunction with CocosBuilder yet. However, the concepts are the same as with the JS bindings.